# Setting a Super's property in a Subclass' __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I ran into an issue where I needed a custom getter with a vanilla setter. The problem happens when I try to set the attribute in a subclass's `__init__`. If I place the `super`'s `__init__` last it will overwrite the set in the `Child` class.

Obviously having the `super` run it's `__init__` first fixes the issue and I've put an `assert` into the `Parent`'s `setx` to make sure the _x has already been initialized.

My question is whether I'm doing something obviously wrong. Having an assert in the setter feels clunky to me.

Note: that I previously didn't initialize the _x in the init until pylint yelled at me.

```
class Parent(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._x = None

  def getx(self):
      return self._x

  def setx(self, value):
      #assert hasattr(self,'_x')
      self._x = value

  x = property(getx, setx)

class Child(Parent):

  def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x
      super(Child, self).__init__() # sets x to None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = Parent()
  p.x = 123
  print p.x # prints 123

  c = Child(321)
  print c.x #prints None
```

Comment: "If I place the super's __init__ last it will overwrite the set in the Child class.".  What's wrong with placing it first?

Comment: Nothing wrong with placing it first. It just felt weird was all. Code works fine with the assert to make sure the init is always in the right place. It was more of a naval gazing question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally prefer the following solution:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self._x = x

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(Child, self).__init__(x)
```